# Google Chat: how to post with picture file using mostly javascript in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, chat

I am working in Google Chat.  I can post text all day long and would like to include a picture file.  Google gives an example of an attachment using JSON, but I am looking for javascript to include a pic within the post.

```
var Body = '..'

// Pic file name in G Drive.
var Picture = DriveApp.getFilesByName('DMS.png');

// I know this needs to be JSON
const payload = JSON.stringify({ text: Body,
                                 imgInput: Picture });
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: payload,
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch(GOOGLE_CHAT_WEBHOOK_LINK, options);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting with this code?

Comment: Exception: Request failed for https://chat.googleapis.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"imgInput\" at 'message': Cannot find field.",
    "st... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: Based on the error, it does not recogonize the field imgInput. From where did you get this JSON that includes imgInput - did you get it in any Google reference doc?

Comment: I did but it wasn't for CHAT.  It might have been for SHEETS.  I was hoping to stumble into the right code for javascript. 

const payload = JSON.stringify({ text: Body,
                                     attachment: Picture });
I was first using this from https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/upload-media-attachments.  No Errors and No Picture was posted.  Just the '..' was posted.

Comment: This question seems quite broad and is not about a specific issue you are facing in the current code, rather how to develop the complete code in JS. So, I'd suggest taking the help of ChatGPT or other tools as a starting point to generate the code, and then reach out if you face any specific issues.

Comment: Thx. I will.  If I find the answer, I'll post it here.